# How to decrypt a single file recovered from a bitlocker encrypted drive

Tags: encryption, data-recovery, bitlocker, single-file

I recovered a deleted text file from a bitlocker encrypted drive using "EaseUS Data Recovery" tool. The recovered file seems to be the raw encrypted bits. Is there a way to decrypt that file since i have the bitlocker password and recovery key? I am aware that you can decrypt a whole drive, but that is not going to work. I just need a way to decrypt that one file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I doubt it is possible. The real encryption key is stored on the harddisk; the bitlocker password (or recovery key) only give you *access* to use that key for decrypting. That real key (which you would need) is never visible / accessible outside the hard disk controller and its memory.

You can verify that by changing your bitlocker password - it takes only milliseconds, because it only is hashed and written onto the hard disk; the encrypted files themselves are never touched, as they still use the same old key.